# View height wrap child views content

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

I want to add a image left of the super view and a custom label center of the superview. Also superview's height must wrap children. Also I am adding superview in to a stack(fill,fill distribution and alignment ). Code is below but imageview not showing. What is problem here?

```
let topView = UIView()
topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.size.width).isActive = true

let backImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
backImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
backImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backButtonClicked)))
backImageView.image = UIImage(named: "backButton")
backImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
backImageView.clipsToBounds = true

topView.addSubview(backImageView)
backImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
backImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.topAnchor).isActive = true
backImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
backImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

topView.addSubview(titleText)
titleText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
titleText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Appologize if it's a dumb question but do you add your `topView` to the `self.view`? Also your top view is missing 2 constraints, such as centerX and centerY

Comment: yes I added it into a stackview and I added  stackview into the superview.label is showing but imageview is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the `backImageView` Y constraint

`backImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true`

should be

`backImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true`

the Y is for **vertical** axix, so in your 4 contraints you have 3 vertical constrains, and 1 horizontal constraint. Replace it with a `centerXAnchor` and you should be good.

[image]

Comment: I want to add imageview left of the superview not center of the superview

Comment: The problem was your `UIImageView` not showing, it's a matter of constraints. Now it is displayed. 
If you want to place it to the left, stick *top*, *bottom* and *left* to the superview, then assign a *width* constant.